# Paged table of data from mysql, auto refreshing

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have been looking at using AJAX and jQuery to achieve what I want to do, but I haven't used either of them very much and I am getting a bit of a headache.

What I would like to do, is to have a table of data displayed from a MySQL database. I would like this table to be paginated, so limited to around 25 results per page.

Finally, I would like a recursive script that fetches a more recent set of results using AJAX or similar.

Without trying to learn all of these things and try to put them all together myself, is there a more compact simple library I can use to achieve this auto updating table of data?

If not, can someone point me to some basic step by step guides on where to start with this?

Comment: Have you seen Table Sorter? http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Comment: Table sorter looks cool, and I see it can append data. I am not sure appending will be ideal, as that might mean I end up with duplicated data? I will certainly look into using it though as it will save me a ton of work otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX SQL call would be like so:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) RowNumber, * FROM my_table)
SELECT ID, column FROM cte
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ".(page*nxtAmnt)+1." AND ".(page+1)*nxtAmnt
```

Where `page` is passed in (via `nxt`) and `nxtAmount` is the number of records per page (25).

You also need buttons to activate it:

```
<div id="pages"></div>
<input type="button" value="Previous" onclick="page('d');"/>
<input type="button" value="Next" onclick="page('u');"/>
```

Your JS would then be

```
var pagCounter=0;
    function page(input){
        if(input=='u')
            pagCounter++;
        else
            pagCounter--;

        if(pagCounter<0){
            pagCounter=0;
        }

        getNext();
    }

    function getNext(){
        if(pagCounter<0)
            pagCounter=0;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "AJAX.php",
            data: "nxt="+pagCounter,
            async: true,
            cache: false,

            success: function(data){ /* called when request completes */
                if(data!=""){
                    $("#pages").html(data);
                }
                else{
                    $("#pages").html("No options found");
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment, here is an explanation of the SQL.

[`WITH cte AS(`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) is kind of like pulling the results into a temp table and then using that.  In this case, the table is named `cte`

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) RowNumber, * FROM my_table)
```

This is the query that populates the `cte` table.  It includes `Row Numbers` (ordered by `ID` DESC) as well as `*`, though you can change this if you want.

```
SELECT ID, column FROM cte
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN ".(page*nxtAmnt)+1." AND ".(page+1)*nxtAmnt
```

This is a normal query using the `cte` table.  We limit the records by keeping results between certain row numbers (which is the page number times records per page).

So, in PHP you can pass in the page number, have the # per page hardcoded (or pass it in as well) and the query will give you what you want.

Comment: Hi, this looks pretty good to me, although I wondering if you could clarify the SQL for me? I assume the WITH cte part is setting up the query, so you are filtering the results, and then the SELECT statement is then getting only a certain number of those results to paginate it. Is this pure SQL or is it MySQL?

Comment: @Eds I've added an **EDIT** to hopefully explain the query.

Comment: Ok so I used all of your code as a good starting point, with a few minor tweaks based on my specific functionality requirements, but the query I couldn't get to work so went and created my own query from scratch. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Eds Glad to help.  I hope the edit assisted in your customizing.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)

To fetch your data again you should do something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $("#myGridId").trigger("reloadGrid");
}, 1000);
```

Use the method `.setPostData()` to change parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a good pre-canned version, but you really only need a couple relatively simple things:

1. A utility page which takes `GET` parameters dictating what rows, and returns them from the DB (easy)
2. On your main page, an AJAX routine that, when called, requests that page and appends it to the bottom of the growing table. (not too hard; the standard AJAX idiom will do most of the work)
3. A way of detecting when to make the table longer, and keeping track of its current length (varies from easy to hard, depending on how fancy you want to make it.  A button is really really easy)

EDIT: Note that as outlined, JQuery is unnecessary -- you can use it and probably simplify a couple of those steps if you would like.